# In $ n < (n^2(s-2)-n(s-4))/2$ can I make it so that one side becomes completely know when I give a value to $s$

Tags: inequality

If I have $$ n < \cfrac{n^2(s-2)-n(s-4)}{2}$$
can I make it so that one side becomes completely known when I give a value to $s$, for example(obv. not true)
$$123n^2+456n+789<987s+654$$
So that I can get a maximum value for $n$

Also $n,s$ are positive integers

Comment: Please avoid using cfrac or dfrac in titles - it makes the title too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n < \frac{n^2(s-2)-n(s-4)}{2}\Rightarrow (s-2)n^2-(s-2)n>0\Rightarrow n(s-2)(n-1)>0$$
Because $n>0$,
$$(s-2)(n-1)>0\Rightarrow s>2,n>1$$

So by fixing $s$ there is no maximum value for $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if I am not mistaking, you can simplify to: 
$$n < \frac{1}{2}(n^2(s-2)-n(s-4)) \\
\Leftrightarrow 2n < n^2(s-2)-n(s-4) \\
\Leftrightarrow 2 < n(s-2)-(s-4) \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{(s-2)} < n-\frac{(s-4)}{(s-2)} \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{(s-2)} +\frac{(s-4)}{(s-2)} < n \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{s-2}{s-2}<n$$

Comment: You have assumed $s-2>0$ when dividing, otherwise the inequality flips.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Actually we only know that s is positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows: $$2n < n^2(s-2)-n(s-4)$$
or, $$ 0 < n^2(s-2)-n(s-2)$$
or, $$ 0 < n(n-1)(s-2)$$